# Finding the centroid of a polar curve

Tags: polar-coordinates

I have absolutely no idea how to find the area centroid of this problem. I have been working at this one for ages but can't seem to get anywhere.

Any first steps? How would one go about solving this?

***Find the centroid of the area by direct integration.***

[image]

Comment: Do you know the general formula for the center of mass? It's sum of the positions vectors times their mass element there. Does that help?

Comment: I understand how to do these problems in general, but this one has me stumped. I am not sure where to begin.

Answer (score 2):

Here we go. Now we want to calculate the centroid $(\overline{r}, \overline{\theta})$ of the area that was defined by a polar function $r = r(\theta), (\alpha \leqslant \theta \leqslant \beta)$.

We know the general formula for centroid:
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
\overline{x} = \dfrac{1}{A}\int_A x \,\mathrm{d}A\\
\overline{y} = \dfrac{1}{A}\int_A y \,\mathrm{d}A
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
For each polar point $(r(\theta), \theta)$ on the curve, we can take a fan-shaped surface element just like the following figure.
[image]
The centroid of this surface element is $\left(\frac{2}{3}r(\theta), \theta\right)$(Why there is a $\frac{2}{3}$ just like you ask? We can consider the surface element as an triangle, and the centroid of this triangle is obviously at here.) The cartesian coordinate of it's centroid is $\left(\frac{2}{3}r(\theta)\cos\theta, \frac{2}{3}r(\theta)\sin\theta\right)$. And the area of this surface element $\mathrm{d}A = \frac{1}{2}r^2(\theta)\mathrm{d}\theta$. So we have
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
\overline{x} = \dfrac{1}{3A}\int_{\alpha}^{\beta} r^3(\theta)\cos\theta \,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
\overline{y} = \dfrac{1}{3A}\int_{\alpha}^{\beta} r^3(\theta)\sin\theta \,\mathrm{d}\theta
\end{aligned}
\right.\\
\mbox{with}~A = \dfrac{1}{2}\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}r^2(\theta)\,\mathrm{d}\theta
$$
Now we get the cartesian coordinate $(\overline{x}, \overline{y})$ of the centroid of the hole form. But we want the polar coordinate $(\overline{r}, \overline{\theta})$. Notice that
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
& \overline{r} = \left|\overline{x}+\mathrm{i}\,\overline{y}\right|\\
& \overline{\theta} = \arg(\overline{x}+\mathrm{i}\,\overline{y})
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
with
$$
\begin{aligned}
\overline{x}+\mathrm{i}\,\overline{y} & = \dfrac{1}{3A}\int_{\alpha}^{\beta} r^3(\theta)\cos\theta \,\mathrm{d}\theta + \mathrm{i}\,\left(\dfrac{1}{3A}\int_{\alpha}^{\beta} r^3(\theta)\sin\theta \,\mathrm{d}\theta\right)\\
& = \dfrac{1}{3A}\int_{\alpha}^{\beta} r^3(\theta)(\cos\theta + \mathrm{i}\,\sin\theta) \,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
& = \dfrac{1}{3A}\int_{\alpha}^{\beta} r^3(\theta)\,\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta} \,\mathrm{d}\theta
\end{aligned}
$$
Finally we have
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
& \overline{r} = \dfrac{1}{3A}\left|\underline{Z}\right|\\
& \overline{\theta} = \arg\left(\underline{Z}\right)
\end{aligned}
\right.\\
~\\
\mbox{with}~A = \dfrac{1}{2}\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}r^2(\theta)\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
\mbox{and}~\underline{Z} = \int_{\alpha}^{\beta} r^3(\theta)\,\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta} \,\mathrm{d}\theta
$$

Now apply this conclusion in this problem. Here, $r(\theta) = a\mathrm{e}^{\theta},(0 \leqslant \theta \leqslant \pi)$. So
$$
\begin{aligned}
A & = \dfrac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi}a^2\mathrm{e}^{2\theta}\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
& = \dfrac{1}{4}a^2(\mathrm{e}^{2\pi}-1)
\end{aligned}
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
\underline{Z} & = \int_{0}^{\pi} a^3\mathrm{e}^{(3+\mathrm{i})\theta}\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
& = -\dfrac{a^3(\mathrm{e}^{3\pi}+1)}{3+\mathrm{i}}
\end{aligned}
$$
So
$$
\begin{aligned}
\overline{r} & = \dfrac{1}{3A}\left|\underline{Z}\right|\\
& = \dfrac{2\sqrt{10}}{15}\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{3\pi}+1}{\mathrm{e}^{2\pi}-1}\,a \approx 9.78\,a
\end{aligned}
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
\overline{\theta} & = \arg(\underline{Z})\\
& = \pi - \arctan \dfrac{1}{3} \approx 161.57^\circ
\end{aligned}
$$
Plot the centroid $C = (\overline{r}, \overline{\theta})$ on the figure:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

So the center of mass is given by $$\int \vec{r} dm$$
Your mass density is uniform. Your limits of integration will be $\theta: (0,\pi)$ and $r: (0,a e^{\theta})$. The Jacobian will be simply $r$. Remember that $\vec{r}=r \cos(\theta) \hat{i} + r\sin(\theta) \hat{j}$. You'll be left with a tricky enough integration, I would advise integrating with respect to $dr$ first.

Can you handle it from here?

Comment: I am not quite sure on the application of the Jacobian here. The solution to this problem is actually in the text. It shows the conversion into polar coordinates first, but `X(bar) = 2/3 r *cos(theta)` and `Y(bar) = 2/3 r* sin(theta)`. Any idea on where the 2/3 scalers came from?

Comment: I see no reason why those $2/3$s should be there... After all the definition is pretty clear. The jacobian arises because you are taking an integral over an area.

Comment: Isn't $dm = dx.dy/A = r.dr.d\theta/A$, where $A$ is the total area? Then $A$ has to be calculated as well.

Comment: @HandeBruijn You are right.

Answer (score 0):

You have already seen the solution to the problem and I see that they have made recourse to complex variables. I would like to demonstrate that the solution might be somewhat simpler if one were to fully embrace the complex plane.

To begin with, for $r=ae^{\theta}$ the curve can be expressed in the complex plane simply as

$$z=ae^{(1+i)\theta}$$

This is seen to be a logarithmic spiral with a flair coefficient of unity, which means that the radius increases by factor $e$ per radian. You'll notice that at $\theta=\pi$ the radius is $r(\pi)=e^{\pi}$. Now, we know that the area and centroid are given by (see reference)

$$
A=\frac{1}{2}\int\Im\{z^*\dot z\}d\theta\\
Z_c=\frac{1}{3A}\int z\ \Im\{z^*\dot z\}d\theta
$$

where $()^*$ is the conjugate and $(^\dot \,)$ is the derivative with respect to $\theta$. Therefore we can calculate the centroid as follows:

$$
\dot z=a(1+i)e^{(1+i)\theta}\\
z^*=ae^{(1-i)\theta}\\
z^*\dot z=a^2(1+i)e^{2\theta}\\
\Im\{z^*\dot z\}=a^2e^{2\theta}\\
$$

Then

$$A=\frac{a^2}{2}\int_0^{\pi}e^{2\theta}\,d\theta=\frac{a^2}{4}(e^{2\pi}-1)\\
\begin{align}
Z_c
&=\frac{a^2}{3A}\int_0^{\pi}e^{(1+i)\theta}e^{2\theta}\,d\theta=\frac{a^2}{3A}\frac{(e^{(3+i)\pi}-1)}{(3+i)}\\
&=\frac{4a}{3}\frac{1}{(3+i)}\frac{(e^{(3+i)\pi}-1)}{(e^{2\pi}-1)}\approx-9.274a+3.091ai
\end{align}
$$

An finally, we can the centroid in polar coordinates from

$$
r_c=|Z_c|\approx9.776a\\
\theta_c=\arg Z_c\approx161.87^{\circ}
$$

It's been my experience that it's much simpler to solve problems like this in the complex plane.

The reference for this work is: Zwikker, C. (1968). *The Advanced Geometry of Plane Curves and Their Applications*, Dover Press.